# C# Set PageSize for Print using ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, printing, processstartinfo

I want to print a file (in my case a pdf) using `ProcessStartInfo`. The problem is I couldn't find a way to set page size of output file. I seems that it prints with default page size. Is there any way to set `PageSize` of the print using `ProcessStartInfo`? I have seen in [ProcessStartInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) there is an `Arguments` property but I couldn't figure out if it is possible to pass pagesize with it.
Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Saeed

Comment: Did you do a search for this before you asked?